# RHEL5.6でIPv6のループバックアドレスを設定したい

Tags: rhel, ipv6

RHEL5.6のサーバに対して新たにソフトを導入することになり、そのソフトの導入要件として「IPv6のループバックアドレスが有効であること」となっておりました。
一般的なループバックアドレスの設定として、hostsファイルへ下記を記入しましたがPingがエラーとなりました。
エラーを回避して、ループバックアドレスで応答するようにするためにはどのように設定すれば良いでしょうか？

**hostsの記載内容**

```
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6 (hostname)
※(hostname)は仮で表記しており、実際はサーバのホスト名が記入されています。
```

**実行したPingコマンド**

```
ping6 -c 3 ::1
```

**実行結果 (エラーメッセージ)**

```
socket: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: `(hostname)` と書かれていますが、これはこのままの通りに /etc/hosts に書いた、という事でしょうか？

Comment: 失礼しました。こちらはホスト名を伏せるために仮で表記しているものとなります。
実際にはIPv6のループバックを設定したいサーバのホスト名が記入されています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS で IPv6 が無効になっているのではないでしょうか？
/etc/modprobe.conf や /etc/modprobe.d/ 以下のファイルで以下のような設定があれば、コメントアウトし、OS を再起動します。

```
alias net-pf-10 off
blacklist ipv6
install ipv6 /bin/true
options ipv6 disable=1
```

再起動後、`ip addr show dev lo` で `inet6` が表示されることを確認ください。

Comment: ご回答いただいた内容で検証してみたところ、Pingコマンドの応答がありました！
ご回答いただき、ありがとうございました！